# How To Avoid sql injections to existing code

Tags: php, mysql

There was a mysql injections on my website.It has 1000 of existing php files. From last 6 months , when i code i keep sure the code is injections free.But is there any solution how can i secure the legacy code without changing every file.

Comment: if there was, there were no injections at all

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago, a legacy application that I was helping support was hacked, and it too had a very large footprint of files. The length of time it was going to take to resolve the issue on all the legacy files was very significant, so we decided to add a Mod Security layer to help mitigate the issue while we worked on rebuilding the application.

If your website is important to you, and you want some extra protection while you search and destroy the vulnerabilities in your code, I would highly recommend Mod Security. You can set it up locally if you manage your own Apache server, or you can setup a proxy server whose only responsibility is to scrub incoming requests. I've used both with a high success rate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very **vast** field. However, There are few points I can give you

- Sanitize and filter every input you receive from the user.
- Handle every errors correctly. Do not even leave one possibility of an error being triggered
  <sup>***(This is a very important point and the main reason of most of the hacks)***</sup>
- If there were previous breaches, check the `apache`'s log files to see where the injection happened. or where the hacking occur.

  1. There are mainly two types of logs file maintained in apache. `access_log` and `error_log`
  2. Once a breach occurs, make a backup of the logs and mitigate the problem, reviewing the logs.
- If a documentation is available for the system you are maintaining currently, then the vulnerability can be detected quicker.

---

#### Some helpful references

1. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
2. http://simon.net.nz/articles/protecting-mysql-sql-injection-attacks-using-php/

[image: How hacking occurs?]

Comment: Reviewed your links. While second has some flaws but viable, the third one just below any quality limits. A pure nonsense.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, really. It is basic, but certainly helpful to give an overview. That's why it was third point too.  `:'( @ -1`

Comment: it is UNHELPFUL giving out a dozen completely rubbish advises like "limit your input lengths" WITHOUT a good solution at all.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel, Imagine a case, where you are expecting a password and text you receive is `500+` chars. I am not trying to judge your expertise on this, but its a pretty good point IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no magic wand to wave. You're going to have to audit any and all code that is exposed to user input (even indirectly) and either verify that it is safe or fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It would involve changing all of your exploitable code if it is in each of these files! There are lots of different ways of having a standardized sanitation function or cleaning and filtering input across your website but if each of these pages were written separately and each have exploitable code in them, you will need to correct each of them...

Answer (score 0):

first off, if you managed to consolidate and organize your code properly, then the issue can be isolated. if injections is the issue, then all you have to look at (if you used an MVC pattern) is all your models. if your methods of doing queries are safe, then at least half of your problems will be washed away just like (snap) that! the rest should be the other half - your validation scripts (which, if you followed MVC, should be classified under "helpers" and "libraries")

however, if your "1000+" PHP code are a bunch of "copy, paste, run-right-off-the-bat", then there is nothing else you can do besides manually peering to each of them, trace and test out the code. besides, reaching that many PHP files, you should have thought about creating a maintainable code.